# Why does Ruby's 'gets' includes the closing newline?

Tags: ruby, newline, language-design

I never need the ending newline I get from `gets`. Half of the time I forget to `chomp` it and it is a pain in the....

Why is it there?

Comment: woodworking saying: you can always cut more wood from a board, but you can't put it back.

Comment: @DGM You can always add "\n".

Comment: @sawa: If you're sure there was one there to start with.

Comment: @Andrew The only case when you don't get one is when you reached EOF. But will that matter?

Comment: `gets` is a standard method in many languages, rooted all the way back to C. Its behavior is the same as C's, which is probably for consistency. I doubt it's going to change, so you probably want to get used to either automatically adding `chomp`, or pay more attention to the data-type you need and add `chomp` only when necessary. It's just one of those chores in programming that we learn to do.

Answer (score 7):

Like `puts` (which sounds similar), it is designed to work with lines, using the `\n` character.

`gets` takes an optional argument that is used for "splitting" the input (or "just reading till it arrives). It defaults to the special global variable `$/`, which contains a `\n` by default.

`gets` is a pretty generic method for readings streams and includes this separator. If it would not do it, parts of the stream content would be lost.

Answer (score 4):

```
var = gets.chomp
```

This puts it all on one line for you.

Comment: This answer does not address the question at all. I wonder why it got upvoted so much.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation of `IO#gets`, you'll notice that the method takes an optional parameter `sep` which defaults to `$/` (the input record separator). You can decide to split input on other things than newlines, e.g. paragraphs ("a zero-length separator reads the input a paragraph at a time (two successive newlines in the input separate paragraphs)"):

```
>> gets('')
dsfasdf
fasfds


dsafadsf    #=> "dsfasdf\nfasfds\n\n"
```

Comment: Still, that begs the question of why it should capture and return the separator -- `"1,2,3".split(',')` doesn't return the commas.  I'd argue (as I did in my answer) that the reason for the discrepancy is that it's no extra "work" to leave the commas out of the result for `split`, but `gets` has to buffer the record separator before it can notice that it's come along.

Comment: Why should it strip the separator? `IO#gets` is used in other contexts too, in some of which stripping the separator may not seem as natural as when directly asking for user input.

Answer (score 0):

From a performance perspective, the better question would be "why should I get rid of it?".  It's not a *big* cost, but under the hood you have to pay to chomp the string being returned.  While you may never have had a case where you *need* it, you've surely had plenty of cases where you don't care -- `gets s; puts stuff() if s =~ /y/i`, etc.  In those cases, you'll see a (tiny, tiny) performance improvement by not chomping.

Comment: I don't think that's it. Ruby is not designed as a fast language, and there is no gain if everyone has to chomp the string anyway.

Comment: Just because Ruby is extremely expressive doesn't mean you can't consider speed.  And like I said, "nobody needs the newline" != "everybody has to chomp".

Answer (score 0):

How I auto-detect line endings:

```
# file open in binary mode
line_ending = 13.chr + 10.chr
check = file.read(1000)
case check
when /\r\n/
  # already set
when /\n/
  line_ending = 10.chr
when /\r/
  line_ending = 13.chr
end
file.rewind

while !file.eof?
  line = file.gets(line_ending).chomp
  ...
end
```