# Why am I not successfully breaking from this Ruby loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, break

I am practising Ruby by writing a simple Blackjack game. When the user is asked whether they want to stick or twist, my program seems to insist they have chosen twist even if they explicitly trigger what should be the break. I have abstracted the problem here:

```
choice = ""
loop do
     print "Press any key to twist. Enter s to stick: "
     choice = gets
     break if choice == "s"
     puts "twist"
end

print "stick"
```

Any idea what is causing a problem in what should be a very simple piece of code? Whatever I do, I can't get 'stick' to print.

Comment: I'm surprised I can't turn up a similar question searching here. This is a common issue easily solved :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432524/why-does-rubys-gets-includes-the-closing-newline

Comment: Chris, while `chomp` is needed for doing comparisons, as here, it is not always needed.  If, for example, `gets` returned '77\n', `gets.to_i` would return the integer 77 (for the same reason that '77abc' returns 77). In spite of this, many Rubiests always append `gets` with `.chomp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `gets` you are storing the input entered along with the `\n` newline character from pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>.  The convention to avoid that is to use `gets.chomp` ([`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chomp)) to strip whitespace from the input.

```
choice = ""
loop do
     print "Press any key to twist. Enter s to stick: "
     choice = gets.chomp
     break if choice == "s"
     puts "twist"
end

print "stick"
```

This is addressed in the [User Input section at ruby-doc.org.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/Tutorial/part_02/user_input.html)

In an `irb` console you can test this by simply doing something like:

```
irb > input = gets
abcde
 => "abcde\n" 
irb > input = gets.chomp
abcde
 => "abcde"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In all the literature I'm using the examples use chomp, but I didn't think I'd need it since I know the program is expecting 's' and I'm typing 's'. I overlooked the fact \n is appended. This had me stuck for ages. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisButcher You're welcome. I'm happy to help. It's a common problem with a common solution.