# Ruby: Until loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby

I just wrote this simple script:

```
#!/bin/env ruby

begin
    print "Continue? [Y/n] "
    key = gets
end until key == 'n'
```

I expect that if I hit "n" key, the loop will end. But that's not happening. No matter what key I send, loop always continue: 
[image: until loop problem]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I not successfully breaking from this Ruby loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820721/why-am-i-not-successfully-breaking-from-this-ruby-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gets` also captures the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you press after the *n*.

Try `key = gets.chomp` instead (see the explanation here: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/Tutorial/part_02/user_input.html#newline).